# How can I have `rosdep install -a` run even when it fails to resolve all packages?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been attempting a gentoo install, and this would be highly useful as `ros/fuerte/swig-wx` is not available there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34013/how-can-i-have-%60rosdep-install--a%60-run-even-when-it-fails-to-resolve-all-packages?/) by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4517/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-25**:
Hey did it work for you?  I'm meaning to try installing groovy on a gentoo machine, but I'm concerned I might get stuck on something I can't solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know it is old, but it is still not answered...
You can pass the robust option -r to the argument, that should do the trick

```
rosdep install -ar
```

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0